# Rollback changes in feature branch git

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, rollback, atlassian-sourcetree

We have the main branches `develop`, `release` and `master` in Bitbucket. `develop` branch is for current development. Team creates `feature` branches from `develop` and they will merge a `feature` branch with `develop` once code changes are done.

In some case, if we find a bug, we have to rollback some particular change which is deployed in `UAT`. So we will create a `bugfix` branch from `release`, rollback the change and merge with `release` and `develop` as well. But some developers might already have started working for the next sprint on newly created `feature` branches. To rollback the same from `feature` branch, what is the best practice when many people work on the same repository?

Since the team is working with **Sourcetree** client instead of command line, it would be helpful if someone could advise how it should be done on Sourcetree.

Comment: The risk that someone is already working on the next feature at the time you merge in a rollback of an old feature, is no different from the risk that someone is working on New Feature X at the time someone else merges New Feature Y.  They'll eventually have to merge or rebase in both cases.  Have feature rollbacks been causing specific problems beyond what you'd see with concurrent feature development?

Comment: No..We just started using git and this scenario is very often in our project.. We want to make sure all our branches have the correct code. we deploy to dev environment from feature branches. so it doesn't have the rollback.  Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to regularly either rebase your feature branches onto develop, or merge from develop into your feature branches.

Imagine a live bug that blocks a developer from working on his feature. The hotfix is released and merged into `develop`. Of course the fix should not be copy/pasted into the feature branch, the hotfix commit should be pulled (either by merge or rebase) from `develop` into the `feature` branch so the developer can continue working in the context of what is currently stable in `develop`.

The decision of whether to rebase or merge is for you to decide - either is a valid choice. There is plenty of discussion regarding the pros and cons of both workflows. For example: https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase

To rebase in Sourcetree: With the feature branch checked out, right click on the dev branch and click rebase.
To be able to push these changes you will need to tick the *Force push* option which must first be enabled in *Tools>Options, Git, Enable Force Push*.

Note that if there are conflicts during the rebase, you'll need to resolve them and then continue the rebase from the Actions menu.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the feature branches are only local branches of the developers? So just make your developers regularly rebase their feature branches against `develop` branch, then they are sure to have their work based on the latest changes on `develop`, including such rollbacks.

Comment: Thanks. They are not local branches..Usually we create feature branches on Bitbucket. So that we can merge using pull request. In such case, rebase feature branches is good practice?

Comment: But you only merge using pull request after the feature is finished, don't you? Before the feature branch is only local, then pushed and merged, not? If not, it depends on whether someone might have based work on the branch. If you rebase a branch, you rewrite its history, so if anyone else is working with that branch or with some branch based on this branch, you should not use rebase, but merge. (same effect but uglier history) If only one developer is actually working with the branch, using rebase is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make `feature` branch works on the latest `develop` branch (rollback changes from feature branch), you can rebase `feature` branch changes when pulling `develop` branch.

Detail steps as: checkout feature branch in source tree -> pull -> select `develop` for **Remote branch to pull** -> select `Rebase instead of merge` for **Options**.

`Note:` If there has conflicts during rebase, you need to manually solve the conflicts and then use the commands `git add .` and `git rebase --continue` one by one, especially when you have many commits on feature branch. Or you can use the command `git pull origin develop --rebase -X ours` to auto solve the conflict files by keeping the version from latest `develop` branch on remote.

Illustrate by graphs:

```
      E---F    feature(HEAD)
     /         
A---B---C---D  develop
```

There has new commit `G` on `develop` branch from remote:

```
      E---F        feature(HEAD)
     /         
A---B---C---D---G  origin/develop
            |
         develop
```

After use `git pull origin develop --rebase`:

```
                  E---F   feature(HEAD)
                 /         
A---B---C---D---G         origin/develop
```